# How to copy Fusion Tables access rights?

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

There is a way to [copy](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/copy) Fusion Table. But it is copied without Share settings. Is there any way either to copy user rights or to assign these Share settings thru API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Drive API for this: see https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing.